# Is it legally required to name used libraries under Apache 2.0 when publishing an Android app?

Tags: apache-2.0, license, android

My Android app contains many libraries licensed under Apache 2.0. According to my understanding, when publishing the app, it is enough to add the following sentence in the app's description: "This app contains libraries licensed under Apache License 2.0", am I correct?

It is not legally required to actually name all the used libraries, according to my understanding of Apache 2.0, please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption is wrong. You need to comply with the entire language of the [Apache license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), and for your case I recommend you carefully read Section 4.

An easy way to comply with the requirements is to have an 'About' page in your app, where you list all of the information related to the libraries you are using, in accordance with the list included in Section 4.